# Immediately-invoked Function Expression for React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I recently started to work inside a react project with existing codebase and almost every components are embraced by IIFE like this :

```
(function() {
    class MyComponent extends React.Component {
     /* Some stuf */    
    }
    module.exports = MyComponent;
}());
```

I know that these immediately-invoked Function Expression are used to keep variable declaration inside but as we are inside a class do we really need this ?

Comment: If you use React, you likely also use bundling tool like Webpack, so you don't need IIFEs at all cause bundlers do this work (IIFE wrapping) for you.

Comment: @hindmost Yep I'm using webpack